# Trying to use strtok to take a file from stdin and input it into a 2D array

Tags: c

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char data_line[100];
    char square[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
    char word_bank[50];
    char *token;

    int size = 0;
    int row = 0;

    fflush(stdin);

    while (fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), stdin)) {

        token = strtok(data_line, " ");
        int col = 0;


        while (token != NULL) {

            square[row][col++] = *token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        size = col;
        row++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("%c ", square[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is my current code

It will not let me add images as I am a new user but here is what it would look like:

```
T A E D Q Q \n
Z H P N I U \n
C K E W D I \n
V U X O F C \n
B P I R G K \n
N R T B R B \n
EXIT\n
THE\n
QUICK\n
BROWN\n
FOX\n
```

After this code, the 2D array `square` should contain each row of characters without the spaces and newline characters.

The file is being redirected to it via `a.exe < data1` and is a file that includes a square word search. The letters are separated by a space on either side and a newline character on the very end of each line. There is a word bank at the bottom that has all the words. For now I am just trying to store the word search into a 2D array for use, but when I use the above code, it does not print out the characters of the 2D array. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. `square[row][col++] = *token;` What is this supposed to do? `*token` is a single character. Is that what you want to copy?

Comment: Thanks! And yeah, its supposed to take each character of the line delimited by a space and add it to the 2D array.

Comment: You mentioned words, not characters in your question... You copy first character of each word in that array

Comment: The words in question is a word search. Each line of the word search is on a new line, and consists of characters separated by spaces. I need to essentially parse the data and grab each character and input it into an array to be able to work with the data.

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and what you get instead.

Comment: Ill edit the actual post with some examples. It would not let me press enter to make it more neatly formatted (no idea why)

Comment: Some extra note: This is a pure text based program. There is no need to add pictures of text.

Comment: Is all that text within the same text file? Or are these 2 files? Also, what is your output and expected output?

Comment: You need to identify the size of the square and only read as many lines as you find columns. Otherwise you will try to put the words at the bottom in your array as well. As you take the number of columns of the very last line and assign it to `size`, you will only print 1 character at all. If you want to store letters without newline, you need to handle newline. You don't do anything to remove it.

Comment: I have done some modifications and it turns out that the code after the while loop is not even running. If I print out the tokens, I get the correct output but the code after the while loop is not executing.

Comment: You should run your code in a debugger. Step through your instructions and watch content of your variables.

Comment: If I run your code, I get exactly 1 character `'T'` which is what I wrote above. `col` is 1 for the line holding `FOX\n`

Answer (score 2):

Issues with your code include:

- `fgets()` will copy the trailing newline into your buffer (as long as there's room), and you do not accommodate that properly.  The easiest fix would probably be to just add a newline to your `strtok()` delimiter strings.
- Your code does not provide a way to distinguish between the puzzle grid and the subsequent word list, so the `while(fgets(...))` loop will read the input all the way to the end and add unwanted characters to the grid.

  If you can assume that the grid is square then after processing the first row, you can determine from the number of columns how many more rows to read.  Otherwise, you'll need either to be told explicitly what dimensions to expect, or to figure out a cleverer way to discriminate between the grid and the word list.
- `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior and generally should not be used.  It especially serves no purpose at the beginning of your program, before anything has been read from `stdin`.
- `char word_bank[50];` is suspicious.  If this is supposed to store the word list then be aware that it provides space for only 50 characters.  That will be enough for the word list in your example, but you could easily find it insufficient for a puzzle with more words.  If you meant to provide for 50 *words* as opposed to 50 *characters*, then it is wholly inadequate.

Comment: So for the first point, when I did accommodate for the newline character, it ended up making one big string instead of separating them. For the second, I was going to get to that once I could figure out how to even get the data into an array (which since posted I have figured out and am now encountering a different issue). The word bank is set to size 50 due to in my assignment it specifies the longest word search will be a 50x50

Comment: Ok I see the problem with the newline character and have fixed that as well. Now I do actually need to discern the difference from the word bank and the actual word search

Comment: @KeaghonChini — at the end of the first row, you know the number of columns.  Therefore, you also know the number of rows in the word square.  If you ever had to deal with non-square word matrices, then you'd look to see if the line contains a blank as the second character.  If there's a blank, you're looking at the word matrix; otherwise, you're looking at words to be found.

Answer (score 0):

> It will not let me add images as I am a new user but here
> is what it would look like...

Good you can not add images yet. You are talking about a file and could instead post the simple content. It is more compact and can help others to help you, since others could just copy and paste from this:

#### contents of `data1.txt`

```
T A E D Q Q 
Z H P N I U 
C K E W D I 
V U X O F C 
B P I R G K 
N R T B R B 
EXIT
THE
QUICK
BROWN
FOX
```

and then run your code with the same data you do. To add `.txt` extension is a convenience since the OS has defaults to open text files.

A (more convenient) day will come when Stack Overflow will have a button to copy the box contents automatically to the clipboard, like Github or Microsoft MSDN does.

#### back to the program

Your code is a bit far from working yet.

```
    fflush(stdin);
    while (fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), stdin))
    {
        token   = strtok(data_line, " ");
        int col = 0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            square[row][col++] = *token;
            token              = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        size = col;
        row++;
    }
```

- `fflush` is not even defined for input streams. Do not use this. You flush a buffer on output only, when you know you need to.
- `fgets` returns a pointer for a reason. Read the manual. Everyday many many programs for students and even professionals loop because of this. **use the pointer returned by `fgets`**: if `fgets` reads nothing then `data_line` in your code goes unchanged and your program goes on for all eternity and beyond.
- `square` is `char square[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]`. This is an array of arrays of single letters. You can not read the words into `square`, and `strtok` will no help you. Since `token` in `char*` `*token` is char and you will get the first letter of each word at the end of `square`. This is not what you want.
- When you are learning and testing display the data read, or use a debugger. Many times things goes out of control and this can save you time.
- do not write a program at once. Never. Test the parts: your input file has 2 sets of data. Your code does not reflect this.

### An example: write code around the data, iteratively

I will show a 3-step way of writing this type of thing. Full code and output is down here. Since I am coding along this may be a bit long of a post.

#### TL;DR

See *"full code and output for the example"*  below

#### 1 - consume the file

Consider this 1st program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LINE 100
#define MAX_SIZE 50
int main(void)
{
    const char* in_file = "data1.txt";
    FILE*       in = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    char  data_line[MAX_LINE];
    size_t      ln = 0;
    char* p = fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), in); 
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%02llu\t[[%s]]\n", ++ln, p);
        p = fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), in);
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

It just consumes your input file and prints the lines as read, surrounded by `[[ ]]`. Here is the output

```
01      [[T A E D Q Q
]]
02      [[Z H P N I U
]]
03      [[C K E W D I
]]
04      [[V U X O F C
]]
05      [[B P I R G K
]]
06      [[N R T B R B
]]
07      [[EXIT
]]
08      [[THE
]]
09      [[QUICK
]]
10      [[BROWN
]]
11      [[FOX
]]
```

and you see the reason for `[[ ]]`: the line breaks are preserved by `fgets` if there is space for then in the string size.

Now we know that the loop consumes the file.

#### 2 - get the `board` data: a 1st abstraction

Now we want to fill `square` in. So good it is a square: if we know the number of columns we know the number of lines. But the input file can be malformed. `square` is

```
    #define MAX_SIZE 50
    char  square[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
```

But we can have less than `50` columns. So for `Board` we can use

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    char square[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
}   Board;

int get_board(Board*, FILE*);
int show_board(Board*, const char*);
```

And this thing can hold any valid `square`.

- `get_board()` gets the address of a board and a handle for an open file and tries to read the letters in.
- `show_board()` does the obvious: prints the board out.

#### 3 - fill in the board with the input data

If we have the 2 operations above, a `main()` like this

```
int main(void)
{
    const char* in_file = "data1.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    Board my_board = {
        .board_limit = MAX_SIZE,
        .side        = 0,
        .square      = {0}
        };
    int res = get_board(&my_board, in);
    printf("get_board() returned %d\n", res);
    fclose(in);
    show_board(&my_board, "[sample data] ");
    return 0;
}
```

- initialize a `Board`.
- open the data file.
- get the board data.
- show data

**output**

Source code is down in the post.

```
[sample data]     Board 6x6 [MAX 50x50]:
      T A E D Q Q
      Z H P N I U
      C K E W D I
      V U X O F C
      B P I R G K
      N R T B R B
```

#### 4 - get the words from data file. Expanding the model

We want to to do this fast, so consider

```
typedef struct
{  // words
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    char   wrd[MAX_WORDS][MAX_SIZE];
} Words;

int get_words(Words*, FILE*);
int show_words(Words*, const char*);
```

The list of words could be part of the `Board` struct, it is a design choice. But keeping the 2 apart makes easy to mix different `Boards` and `Words`.

The code is almost the same as before, since both are simple *containers*. Just copy and paste and adapt.

If we have also these 2 operations then this code for `main` will **read the board and the words from the input file**:

```
int main(void)
{
    const char* in_file = "data1.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    // get board data
    Board my_board = {
        .board_limit = MAX_SIZE, .side = 0, .square = {0}};
    int res = get_board(&my_board, in);
    if (res != 0) return -2;
    show_board(&my_board, "[from sample data] ");
    // get the words
    Words my_words = {.limit = MAX_WORDS, .size = 0};
    res            = get_words(&my_words, in);
    if (res != 0) return -3;
    fclose(in);
    show_words(&my_words, "[from sample data] ");
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

Source code is down in the post.

```
[from sample data]     Board 6x6 [MAX 50x50]:
        T A E D Q Q
        Z H P N I U
        C K E W D I
        V U X O F C
        B P I R G K
        N R T B R B

[from sample data]     5 words [MAX 50]:
        "EXIT"
        "THE"
        "QUICK"
        "BROWN"
        "FOX"
```

#### *"full code for the example"*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 100
#define MAX_SIZE 50
#define MAX_WORDS 50

typedef struct
{  // board
    size_t side;
    size_t board_limit;
    char   square[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
} Board;

int get_board(Board*, FILE*);
int show_board(Board*, const char*);

typedef struct
{  // words
    size_t size;
    size_t limit;
    char   wrd[MAX_WORDS][MAX_SIZE];
} Words;

int get_words(Words*, FILE*);
int show_words(Words*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    const char* in_file = "data1.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    // get board data
    Board my_board = {
        .board_limit = MAX_SIZE, .side = 0, .square = {0}};
    int res = get_board(&my_board, in);
    if (res != 0) return -2;
    show_board(&my_board, "[from sample data] ");
    // get the words
    Words my_words = {.limit = MAX_WORDS, .size = 0};
    res            = get_words(&my_words, in);
    if (res != 0) return -3;
    fclose(in);
    show_words(&my_words, "[from sample data] ");
    return 0;
}

// gets `square` data from the open file 'in'
// return 0 for success
int get_board(Board* brd, FILE* in)
{
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    if (brd == NULL) return -2;
    char  data_line[MAX_LINE];
    char* p = fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), in);
    if (p == NULL) return -3;  // no data on file
    size_t col = 0;
    size_t row = 0;

    // now loop thru 'p' and get the number of columns
    char* token = strtok(data_line, " ");
    while ((token != NULL) && (*token != '\n'))
    {
        brd->square[row][col] = *token;
        ++col;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    brd->side = col;
    // read the remaining lines
    for (size_t r = 1; r < brd->side; r += 1)
    {
        p = fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), in);
        if (p == NULL) return -4;  // missing data
        char* token = strtok(data_line, " ");
        for (size_t c = 0; c < brd->side; c += 1)
        {
            if (token == NULL) return -5;
            brd->square[r][c] = *token;
            token             = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int show_board(Board* brd, const char* msg)
{
    if (brd == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    Board %llux%llu [MAX %dx%d]:\n", brd->side,
        brd->side, MAX_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);
    for (size_t r = 0; r < brd->side; r += 1)
    {
        printf("\t");
        for (size_t c = 0; c < brd->side; c += 1)
            printf("%c ", brd->square[r][c]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int get_words(Words* W, FILE* in)
{
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    if (W == NULL) return -2;
    char  data_line[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    char* p = NULL;
    while ((p = fgets(data_line, sizeof(data_line), in)) !=
           NULL)
    {                                        // got one word
        if (W->size == W->limit) return -3;  // full
        size_t len = strlen(p);
        if (*(p + len - 1) == '\n') *(p + len - 1) = 0;
        if (*p == 0) continue;  // blank line
        strcpy((char*)W->wrd[W->size], p);
        ++W->size;
    }
    return 0;
}

int show_words(Words* W, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %llu words [MAX %llu]:\n", W->size, W->limit);
    for (size_t c = 0; c < W->size; c += 1)
        printf("\t\"%s\"\n", W->wrd[c]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### conclusion

This is a simplistic way to go: No memory allocation, just 4 functions. The purpose is just to show an iterative way of writing this type of code. Just 3 programs:

- the first just read the file
- the second read the square data
- the third also read the words.

All 3 ran ok at first try. There is a minimal error checking that just cancel the program. As usual the functions returns `0` for ok or a negative status.

HIH